Justifying that the gold nucleus is at rest in a Rutherford experiment
This is an example on the Rutherford Experiment from Young and Freedman's University Physics.
In the last paragraph of the solution the book states that it is valid to assume that the gold nucleus remains at rest because the kinetic energy of the gold nucleus is only $2%$ of the total energy in this situation.
The gold nucleus has a speed of $3.0 \times 10^5 $m/s according to the calculations. When the alpha particle and the gold nucleus collide, the alpha particle has zero kinetic energy and so its energy $4.6$ MeV is all converted into potential energy, which also be the potential energy for the gold nucleus, and the total energy of the gold nucleus is $4.692$ MeV. But why does the fact that most of the energy is potential energy for the gold nucleus justify in assuming that the gold nucleus is at rest?
Indeed I see this sort of assumption often when two masses are orbiting such as the proton and the electron or the sun and the earth, and we assume that the proton or the sun is at rest due to being much more massive than the electron or the earth orbiting around it. I would greatly appreciate if someone could clearly explain why this is a valid assumption.


There is a frame of reference, called centre of momentum frame, or more commonly as centre of mass frame, whereby the alpha particle and the gold nucleus are moving towards each other with equal and opposite momenta. That is the frame of reference whereby the system momentarily stops. You can mathematically prove that using the reduced mass scheme always works, and gets you the same results.

3E5 << 1.5E7. But, feel free to do the calculation in the center-of-mass frame.

@naturallyInconsistent I can see how the com frame argument works but how can we make the same conclusion by seeing that the kinetic energy being only 2% of the total energy?

Much easier to visualise in center of mass system. This takes out the kinetic energy that is not involved in collision and does not change. The center of mass kinetic energy in MeV is given by E = 1.44 z1z2/R where z1 and z2 are atomic numbers and R the distance of approach in Fermi. This energy can be converted to the energy of incident particle in lab by E*(M1+M2)/M2.

If greater accuracy is required replace 1.44 by 1.43997
